# How to know .net core webapi is idle?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core minimal api that maps GET and POST to some function calls.

How do I know that the application is idle and not processing incoming requests?

Are there any nuget that monitors the state of the application and has hooks that can be subscribed to get notified of changing states?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use Prometheus to monitor the API usage. i would interested to know the usecase here, why would you want to know if API is not processing any incoming requests ?

Comment: I think this is based on how you deploy your api application and how to set up the server configuration. for example, if we publish api project to IIS, they we can set it to `alwaysrunning` then there will be not idle all the time